# Page navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

I have dynamic page that gets a query string and load the current page according to the parameter, the URL is like "dynamic.aspx?p=" and p is the parameter.
All the page are in the same directory and has different name like "about" , "contact" and so on.

The question is how I can make next and prev button to move between the pages without going back to the page where all the link are?

I think I can do to with javascript where I take the currnet page URL and with switch-case assigned the URL to the next and prev button, is there is better way?

I am using asp.net , C# and javascript.

[edit]
Forgot to add that I can do it also on the code behind that sound better because it run on server side

Comment: store the current pgae value from querystring and store it in a hiddenfield assign it to the prev button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on the server side. Something along those lines:

```
var strPrev="";
var strNext="";
switch(Request.QueryString["p"])
{
  case "about":
    strPrev="last";
    strNext="contact";
    break;
  case "contact":
    strPrev="about";
    strNext="last";
    break;
  case "last":
    strPrev="contact";
    strNext="about";
}
```

Of course there are ways to express this more concise (arrays) or to make it more flexible (configuration files or databases). Let me know if you want to go in that direction.

**Update**: Here's a solution where the pages are listed in an array:

```
var pages = new string[] { "about", "contact", "last" };
var index = Array.IndexOf(pages, Request.QueryString["p"]);
var previousPage = pages[(index + pages.Length - 1) % pages.Length];
var nextPage = pages[(index + 1) % pages.Length];
```

In this solution the pages are listed in the array (Line #1). The second line converts the textual representation into a number (zero to two). If the page cannot be found `Array.IndexOf` will return -1, this represents the last item of the array (because of wrap-around). And the last two lines get the previous or next item from the array, with wrap-around.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like this, if I use array will the code be easier to maintain ?
I think that I will using this option because I need different background color to the pages.
How I work with the array? I do not need database even not access

Comment: Thanks Simon, I did it as you wrote above, I did not use the array, the first example is fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current pgae value from querystring and store it in a hiddenfield and assign the prev page to another hiddenfield, have a logic to do this. since navigating page is going to be in server side , make the process server side too. It may be easy than doing it in javascript